# ConfigureAwait(true) not returning on the context it was awaited on

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Sample :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     int counter = 0;
     var t = new System.Timers.Timer();
     t.Interval = 3000;
     t.Elapsed += async (sender, e) =>  
     {
        Debug.WriteLine("Before await - Thread : {0} , Counter : {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, counter);
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Debug.WriteLine("Ater await Thread : {0}, Counter : {1} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, counter);

         counter++;
         if (counter == 2)
         {
            Debug.WriteLine("Stop");
            t.Stop();
         }
     };

     t.Start();

     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

this always outputs :

```
 Before await - Thread : 4 , Counter : 0 
 Ater await Thread : 4, Counter : 0  
 Before await - Thread : 5 , Counter : 1 
 Ater await Thread : 4, Counter : 1  

 Stop
```

Why didn't it return on the thread await was called on. it does the first time but then the timer runs on thread 5 and is suppose to capture the context for when the async operation ends, and as you can see it returns on thread 4.

Comment: Works fine for me even in console app

Comment: @msmolcic maybe by chance make the if stop at 6 or something and see if it still does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any synchronization context in console app.

If you run your code in WinForms and you'd see it would work as you expected..

Comment: is there a way i could associate background threads with a synchronization context ? 

i would really wan't every call to return on the same thread that called it.

Comment: @eranotzap You can add `Form1 form = new Form1();` at the beginning of your code for ex.

Answer (score 4):

> Why didn't it return on the thread await was called on.

`await` resumes on the same *context*, not the same *thread*. Sometimes these are the same - notably in UI applications, the UI context is tied to a specific UI thread. Other times there's no correlation - ASP.NET for example has a request context, which is not tied to a specific thread. In this case, the Console app is using the thread pool context, so the method resumes on a thread pool thread.

> is there a way i could associate background threads with a synchronization context ?

This is an extremely rare requirement. Often times developers only *think* they need this. My first recommendation is to remove the specific threading requirement from whatever code requires it, e.g., replacing `ThreadStatic` with more modern solutions.

However, if you really must use background threads with synchronization contexts, then you can use [`AsyncContext.Run` from my `AsyncEx` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).